# Magento Dataflow product import not importing super_attribute fields

Tags: csv, magento, import, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm in the process of testing various methods to import a substantial list of products from an older cart system into Magento Community edition (1.7.0.2).

I'm aware of utilities like Magmi, but we're hoping to explore the simpler solutions first.

Currently I'm looking to export a CSV file from our old cart to use with Magento's built in import/Dataflow option. Before getting there however I'm running tests with existing Magento products exported with Magento's export/Dataflow tools, and am having trouble getting Magento to read and associate the attribute sets/codes for configurable products.

I've tried all the combinations (simple export to simple import, simple to dataflow, dataflow to simple, dataflow to dataflow) before narrowing down a Dataflow export to Dataflow import as almost successful. However, Dataflow export does not include super_attribute fields. I have tried adding them manually using both the simple Import field keys (IE: `_super_products_sku`, `_super_attribute_code`, and `_super_attribute_option`) as well as without the leading _underscore.

I have had no success getting the attributes/sets imported; the process completes without errors and the products are created, however none of the configurable products have attribute sets and none of the simple products are assigned to their configurable "parent".
None of the super_ attributes are selectable for manual mapping in Dataflow, leading me to wonder whether this is even possible.

Here's an example of our header and a product row, comma-separated:

```
store,websites,attribute_set,type,category_ids,sku,has_options,name,image,small_image,thumbnail,url_key,url_path,options_container,country_of_manufacture,price,weight,msrp,status,visibility,enable_googlecheckout,tax_class_id,size_shirt,description,short_description,special_from_date,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,low_stock_date,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,stock_status_changed_automatically,use_config_enable_qty_increments,product_name,store_id,product_type_id,product_status_changed,product_changed_websites,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,size_waist,color,size_hat,meta_title,meta_description,custom_design,page_layout,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,gift_message_available,special_price,is_recurring,meta_keyword,custom_layout_update,special_to_date,news_from_date,news_to_date,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,recurring_profile,super_products_sku,super_attribute_code,super_attribute_option
admin,base,apparel,simple,12,13,30258-XS,0,N O-Skin Short Sleeve Rash Guard Black-XS,,,,n-o-skin-short-sleeve-rash-guard-black-xs,n-o-skin-short-sleeve-rash-guard-black-xs.html,Block after Info Column,United States,29.9500,0.7000,39.9500,Enabled,Not Visible Individually,Yes,Taxable Goods,XS,N O-Skin Rash guard. This second skin is top notch.,N O-Skin Rash guard. This second skin is top notch.,,0.0000,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1.0000,1,0.0000,1,1,,0.0000,0,1,1,1,1,0.0000,1,0,0,1,1,N O-Skin Short Sleeve Rash Guard Black-XS,0,simple,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,30258-XS,size_shirt,XS
```

From what I've been able to find in other Stack Overflow questions and the Magento forums it sounds like there's no reason the above shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, the attribute set is case sensitive. You can find the attribute set names by querying in the database: `SELECT DISTINCT attribute_set_name FROM eav_attribute_set`. So yours probably needs to be `Apparel`.

As for super attributes, I'm not sure that they work with Dataflow.

Comment: the value in the DB is lowercase `apparel`, though I'll try capitalizing it in both the DB and CSV.  While the example I gave is from custom product data I've also tried (and been unable) to export/import Configurables using Magento's sample data.  I haven't found any confirmation one way or another whether Dataflow works with super attributes, but this also seems to imply that Dataflow simply can't handle configurable products out of the box, which seems a pretty big shortcoming.  I'll follow up after I've tried your suggestion.